# Creating Magento orders programmatically

Tags: magento, product

Is there a way that an order can be created within Magento with a "custom" product which would be defined within the order. The order wouldn't require the custom products to be created. These custom products would have custom prices and a custom product title determined when creating the order.

So when creating order, I would just simply specify some custom products with the prices then add them to the order.

Again, the products will not be defined anywhere within Magento, so I would just say, I want to add xyz at 9.99 and zxy at 1.99 and maybe I want to add another xyz at 3.99.

The order would show as,

xyz | 9.99

zxy | 1.99

xyz | 3.99

TOTAL | 15.97

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programatically create an order with custom product is possible, here is an example code:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$order = create();
echo $order;

function create()
{


        $storeId = 1;
        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())->getStoreIds();
            reset($storeIds);
            $storeId = current($storeIds);
        }

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->setState('new');

        $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
              ->setStoreId($storeId)
              ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
              ->setMethod('checkmo')
              ->setPo_number(' - ');
            $order->setPayment($orderPayment);

        $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
        $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');


        $order->setStoreId($storeId)
              ->setQuoteId(0)
              ->setGlobal_currency_code('EUR')
              ->setBase_currency_code('EUR')
              ->setStore_currency_code('EUR')
              ->setOrder_currency_code('EUR')
              ->setStatus($orderData['status']);

              // set Customer data
              $order->setCustomer_email('a@b.com')
              ->setCustomerFirstname('firstname')
              ->setCustomerLastname('lastname')
              ->setCustomer_is_guest(1);

              // set Billing Address
              $billingAddress
              ->setStoreId($storeId)
              ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
              ->setPrefix('mr')
              ->setFirstname('firstname')
              ->setLastname('lastname')
              ->setCompany('company')
              ->setStreet('street')
              ->setCity('city')
              ->setCountry_id('US')
              ->setPostcode('12345');

              $order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

              $shippingAddress
              ->setStoreId($storeId)
              ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
              ->setPrefix('mr')
              ->setFirstname('firstname')
              ->setLastname('lastname')
              ->setCompany('company')
              ->setStreet('street')
              ->setCity('city')
              ->setCountry_id('US')
              ->setPostcode('12345');


              $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
              ->setShipping_method('freeshipping_freeshipping')
              ->setShippingDescription('Free Shipping - Free');


                $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                    ->setStoreId(1)
                    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                    ->setTotalQtyOrdered(10)
                    ->setQtyOrdered(10)
                    ->setName('custom product name')
                    ->setPrice(100)
                    ->setBasePrice(10)
                    ->setOriginalPrice(10)
                    ->setRowTotal(1000)
                    ->setBaseRowTotal(1000);

                    $order->addItem($orderItem);


                $order->setSubtotal(2000)
                    ->setSubtotalIncludingTax(2000)
                    ->setBaseSubtotal(2000)
                    ->setGrandTotal(2000)
                    ->setBaseGrandTotal(2000)
                    ->setTaxAmount(0)
                    ->setTotalQtyOrdered(10);

              $order->save();


    return $order;
}
```

?>

Comment: thank you for the concise answer! Question: that new custom product created for this order; does it remain in Magento or does it only appear when performing actions having to do with this order?

Comment: This way the product is not created - this was one condition of the original question. Magento stores the order item data in the `sales_flat_order_item` redundant, it is independent of the `catalog_product_entity` and related tables. So you can not do any other actions with it, only the actual order-related issues.